# Is it possible to create your own BADI or change document for when a BAPI is called?

Tags: abap

If I find a BAPI which does not have any BADI or change document triggered in SAP when it is called, is it possible to create my own in order to detect when it is called?

Comment: You can change the standard by requesting an access key or by using the Enhancement Framework. And of course, you may create your own BAdI and change document. But your question is [way too broad for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), please focus more.

Comment: This question seems a bit confused. Creating a change document isn't that hard, but what do you mean with "create an own BADI"? BAdI's are a technology for injecting customer code into standard processes. Why exactly do you want to create an own? What exactly is your goal?

Comment: Also note that not all software components use primarily BAdI's for allowing customer code extensions. There are lots of extension technologies in use. Some use different flavors of event function modules, some use user-exits, some use enhancement points, some use something entirely different.